# Displaying list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell

```
displayContacts         :: Contact ->[String]

displayContacts []      =   []

displayContacts (x :xs) =    [show (x)] ++  displayContacts (xs)
```

after performing above function following result showing with exta "\" why is that and how to overcome this

```
["(\"Fazaal\",\"Naufer\",7712345678)","(\"Tharanga\",\"Chandasekara\",779876543)"," 
(\"Ruaim\",\"Mohomad\",7798454545)","(\"Yasitha\",\"Lokunarangoda\",7798121212)","
(\"Rochana\",\"Wimalasena\",779878787)","(\"Navin\",\"Dhananshan\",77987345678)","
(    \"Akila\",\"Silva\",7798123123)","(\"Sudantha\",\"Gunawardana\",779812456)"]
```

i want to display this as "Fazaal" "Naufer" 7712345678 likewise

in my function contact is list of tupples :- [("Isuru","Ranaisnghe",123)]

Comment: Doesn't `print xs` do what you want? What exactly do you want different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you show a  string, `show "hello"`, the show instance for `String` adds in quotes, which are escaped when GHCi prints out a data structure.

There are a few solutions, depending on what your goal is.  If you just want cleaner output in GHCi then:

```
putStrLn $ unlines $ displayContacts contact
```